# SQL Server DateTimeOffset changes the offset of a tz aware datetime to the system offset when using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, datetimeoffset

I have a problem uploading a timezone aware datetime from python to the SQL server datatype datetimeoffset.

No matter which timezone upload to SQL Server, it always displays the offset in system time offset. It is not converting the actual datetime with only changing the offset.

```
    datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
    timeString = datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
    timeData = {'datetimeOFFSET':datetime, 'datetime':datetime, 'datetimeString':timeString}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=timeData, index = np.array([1]))
```

The dataframe in python:

```
datetimeOFFSET                         datetime                           datetimeString
2019-12-30 10:29:07.913715+00:00       2019-12-30 10:29:07.913715+00:00   2019-12-30 10:29:07+0000
```

The result in sql server:

[image]

What I want is the datetimeOFFSET column to display the right offset (+00:00) and not the system offset (+01:00).

Answer (score 2):

Update, April 2021:

This remains a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30884) with pandas `.to_sql()`

---

*Original Answer (Warning: Includes outdated SQLAlchemy 1.3 usage patterns deprecated in version 1.4)*

There have been some very recent (as in "this morning") improvements to `datetimeoffset` handling in SQLAlchemy. They will be included in the next release (probably 1.3.13), but in the meantime try installing from the latest source for the 1.3.x branch ...

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy@rel_1_3
```

... and see if that works better for you.

**Edit:**

On further investigation it appears that the issue lies with `to_sql`. If the DataFrame contains a single row then the timezone offset is lost:

```py
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)

# test environment
table_name = 'DateTimeOffset_Test'
engine.execute(sa.text(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [{table_name}]"))
engine.execute(sa.text(f"CREATE TABLE [{table_name}] (id int primary key, dto datetimeoffset)"))

# test data
my_tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-7))
dto_value = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=my_tz)
print(dto_value)  # 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
#                                        ^

num_rows = 1
row_data = [(x, dto_value) for x in range(num_rows)]
df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=['id', 'dto'])
print(df)
#    id                       dto
# 0   0 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
#                            ^
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
result = engine.execute(sa.text(f"SELECT id, CAST(dto as varchar(50)) AS foo FROM [{table_name}]")).fetchall()
pprint(result)
# [(0, '2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00')]
#                                     ^ -- wrong
```

However, if the DataFrame contains more than one row then the datetimeoffset values are uploaded correctly:

```py
# ...

num_rows = 2
row_data = [(x, dto_value) for x in range(num_rows)]
df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=['id', 'dto'])
print(df)
#    id                       dto
# 0   0 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
# 1   1 2020-01-01 00:00:00-07:00
#                            ^
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
result = engine.execute(sa.text(f"SELECT id, CAST(dto as varchar(50)) AS foo FROM [{table_name}]")).fetchall()
pprint(result)
# [(0, '2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 -07:00'), 
#  (1, '2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 -07:00')]
#                                     ^ -- correct
```

If you really feel strongly about this you might want to raise a [pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) about it.

Comment: Using, for example, df.to_sql gives me the same error but in a different way. Instead of displaying the system time offset, it displays a UTC offset of +00:00 no matter the real offset of the data. df.to_sql("DateTimeOffset_Test", if_exists='append', con=engine, index=False) --> https://imgur.com/C9nyXej

Comment: I appreciate the well-explained answer. But unfortunately, it does not solve my problem: [code and result](https://imgur.com/Ym8NSj4). This could due to an issue on my SQL Server.

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler to see just what is being sent to the server? When I run it I see `exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 datetimeoffset',N'INSERT INTO [DateTimeOffset_Test] (id, dto) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',1` followed by `exec sp_execute 2,0,'2020-01-01 00:00:00 -07:00'` and `exec sp_execute 2,1,'2020-01-01 00:00:00 -07:00'`

Comment: You are right! It is being sent wrong to the server, but I do not understand why: `exec sp_describe_undeclared_parameters N'INSERT INTO [DateTimeOffset_Test] ([datetimeOFFSET], datetime, [datetimeString]) VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3)'` followed by `exec( sp_execute 2,'2020-01-06 10:16:31.2300000 +01:00','2020-01-06 10:16:31.2310000',N'2020-01-06 10:16:31+0000')`. As you can see when the datetime is sent as string (third column), it is sent correct, but not when it is tz aware datetime (first column).

Comment: btw. the +01:00 added is my local timeoffset

Comment: What version of pyodbc are you using? Are you specifying `fast_executemany=True` in your `create_engine` call? Have you tested with a DataFrame that contains more than one row?

Comment: I have found the issue, it is `fast_executemany=True`. The time offset error appears when it is set to True when I set it to false the data is loaded correctly. But this can not be the solution because, without fast_executemany set to True, the upload is way too slow.

Comment: Are you using `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` ?

Comment: yes I am, `engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myDatabaseInformation?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", pool_pre_ping=True, fast_executemany=True)`

Comment: I found that it works with fast_executemany when sending the DateTime with an offset as a plain string instead of DateTime dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this options ?

```
Time zone offset aware and preservation     No
Daylight saving aware                       No
```